# Resize the windows and get a stylish scroll bar for the menu

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

what parameters do i have to add in my NavBar.css (i.e menu in left side) if I want to see a scroll bar (in transparent white) appearing when i resize my windows (i.e I can scroll down or up if the window is not at the max so I can still scroll the menu and see the other icons) please ?

```
.NavBar{
  width: 15rem;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FF7F50 ;
  flex-direction: colums;
  gap: 1.25rem

}
```

This is what i want to have not in green but in transparent/grey bar .

[image]

Comment: [CSS Tricks - The Current State of Styling Scrollbars in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars-in-css/) plus you will need overflow-y: auto; to add vertical scroll bar when content is larger than container.

Answer (score 0):

### Scroll the body:

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Stop the body expanding */
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  /* Tells the element to scroll instead of the default of visbily overflowing */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Scrollbar and scrollbar gutter colors */
  scrollbar-color: #888 transparent;
}

nav {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 110vh;
  background-color: #FF7F50;
  /* gap and flex-direction will do nothing as this element uses flow layout (flex hasn't been declared) */
  flex-direction: colums;
  /* Even then, colums has a typo */
  gap: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  test
</nav>
```

### Scroll the nav:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Tells the element to scroll instead of the default of visbily overflowing */
  background-color: #FF7F50;
  scrollbar-color: white transparent;
  /* Scrollbar and scrollbar gutter colors */
}

nav>h1 {
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>Pineapple is good on pizza</h1>
</nav>
```

Comment: I managed to add this scroll bar but I wanted one with round borders the same shape as the green one image :)

Comment: @Zokulko I don't think there is a way to force round borders, but most UAs render round borders when you set `scrollbar-width` to `thin`